# how to block domains that pointing to my server IP in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04

I have shifted my server from godaddy to Linode VPS. For a strange reason, other than my own domain names, there are some other websites also pointing to my server IP address.

**I have installed LAMP.**

I guess this could be due to some people might have used this server before but didn't update to their new server IP address.

I have searched around and found 1 solution but it doesn't work at all.

I modify this file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

**Blocking any domains other than my own domains.**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Require all denied
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myowndomain1.com
    <Location />
        Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myowndomain2.com
    <Location />
        Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

anyone know what's wrong here? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your catchall, delete the actual ServerName line entirely.

Consider to follow exactly the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#http-configuration) and use a separate file for each virtual host or site, and then leave the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in its original form.